# Ignoring diacritics in orderBy in RethinkDB?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

The query `r.table('categories').orderBy('name')` returns my documents in the following order:

- Cerveja
- Refrigerante
- Suco
- Água

The correct order would take "Água" first:

- Água
- Cerveja
- Refrigerante
- Suco

How can I make `orderBy` ignore the diacritics?

Answer (score 1):

ReThinkDB doesn't support sorting with Unicode collations (see https://rethinkdb.com/docs/data-types/), so I would save an ASCII version of the name in a separate field for sorting and use the current one for display.